# Single file program with PDCurses fails to compile with "undefined reference to"

Tags: c, mingw

I have some problems compiling my test program using PDCurses library. I have compiled PDCurses 3.4 with MinGW compiler 8.2.0. In output I have 2 files panel.a and pdcurses.a. I copied them to C:\MinGW\lib plus the header file curses.h in C:\MinGW\include. But when I try to compile test program I have errors. It seems I have done everything correctly according to instructions and how-to`s.

Some testing C code:

```
#include <C:\MinGW\include\curses.h>

int main () {
    initscr();
    mvprintw( 5, 5, "Hello, World!" );
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

ERRORS:

```
c:/Users/username/Dropbox/rakshasa/main.c:4: undefined reference to `initscr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/username/Dropbox/rakshasa/main.c:5: undefined reference to `mvprintw'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/username/Dropbox/rakshasa/main.c:6: undefined reference to `stdscr'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/username/Dropbox/rakshasa/main.c:6: undefined reference to `wgetch'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/Users/username/Dropbox/rakshasa/main.c:7: undefined reference to `endwin'
```

I have no idea why it is not compiling properly. It looks like compiler cant find libraries in linking stage but I do not know why.

I was try to compile like 
gcc -g main.c -o main.exe

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might start by finding out why the compiler couldn't find the reference to `initscr`.

Comment: You have to tell the linker step whoch objects to link and which libraries to use. Simply placing files in a lib dir often isn't enough. You may need to adapt the makefile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: ...and the relevant answer is [Failure to link against appropriate libraries/object files or compile implementation files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/1362568)

Answer (score 0):

Never use absolute paths in `#include` directives. Instead of `#include <C:\MinGW\include\curses.h>` you should put `#include <curses.h>` and compile with `-IC:\MinGW\include` flag if needed.

Next you need to link with the relevant library using `-lpdcurses`. If needed you can add the location of the library using `-LC:\MinGW\lib`.

So if we split compilation and linking steps you need the following commands:

```
gcc -g main.c -c -o main.o -IC:\MinGW\include
gcc main.o -o main.exe -lpdcurses -LC:\MinGW\lib
```

though I think you can leave out the `-I` and `-L` flags as they point to the location of your compiler's `include` and `lib` folders.

Finally: MinGW is a bit outdated and so is GCC 8.2.0. I recommend you switch to MinGW-w64 (which supports both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows). To get a more recent MinGW-w64 GCC build, you can try the standalone builds from https://winlibs.com/.